# Can't keep hidden overflow when adding new images to div

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm writing a function that add an image (from an array) inside a container div at the coordinates of there the user clicked in that moment.

The problem is that I can't keep the container dimension fixed, I don't know why it keeps enlarge whenever I add an image close to its border.

Another problem I'm facing is that I can't get the img height unless I've placed it in the div but I need to have that information while creating the image because I need to place it in the middle of the clicked point.

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  
  //setup variables
  var arrayImgs = ['https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/eb/ad/3d/crazy-cat-cafe.jpg','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Chairman_Meow_Bao.jpg/1200px-Chairman_Meow_Bao.jpg','https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg','https://cdn.britannica.com/91/181391-050-1DA18304/cat-toes-paw-number-paws-tiger-tabby.jpg'];
  var imgIndex = 0;
  
  
 document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(trigger => {
  trigger.addEventListener('click', function(){
    
      if (imgIndex >= arrayImgs.length){
        //check index to loop array
        imgIndex = 0;
      }
      var imgToAdd = document.createElement("img");
      var container = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      
      imgToAdd.setAttribute("src", arrayImgs[imgIndex]);
      imgToAdd.classList.add('class-img');

      var x = event.clientX;  
      var y = event.clientY;
    
      //generate a random width form the image
      var rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 33) + 20;
      var imgWidth = ((window.innerWidth / 100) * rndInt);
      
      //parse image width
      imgWidth = Math.floor(imgWidth);

      imgToAdd.setAttribute("width", imgWidth );
      imgToAdd.setAttribute("height", "auto" );
      var imgHeight = imgToAdd.height;
      
      //place the image in the middle of mouse X and Y
      imgToAdd.style.position = "absolute";
      imgToAdd.style.left = (x - (imgWidth / 2))+'px';
      imgToAdd.style.top = (y - (imgWidth / 2))+'px';
      
      container.appendChild(imgToAdd);
      imgIndex = imgIndex + 1;
  });
 });
});
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.class-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: bounce 1s;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s;
  -moz-animation: bounce 1s;
}
```

```html
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
<div id="myCanvas" class="container">CLICK ME</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that the imgs are placed with `position: absolute` but their container does not have any position set so they are placed in relation to the nearest ancestor which does have a position set (all the way back to body if there is nothing else). So it is the body overflowing (or whatever the nearest positioned ancestor is) hence you get scrollbars.

You need to give #mycanvas (the container) a position. Then the imgs will be placed in relation to that and the `overflow: hidden` will work. This snippet gives it `position: relative`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  
  //setup variables
  var arrayImgs = ['https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/eb/ad/3d/crazy-cat-cafe.jpg','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Chairman_Meow_Bao.jpg/1200px-Chairman_Meow_Bao.jpg','https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg','https://cdn.britannica.com/91/181391-050-1DA18304/cat-toes-paw-number-paws-tiger-tabby.jpg'];
  var imgIndex = 0;
  
  
 document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(trigger => {
  trigger.addEventListener('click', function(){
    
      if (imgIndex >= arrayImgs.length){
        //check index to loop array
        imgIndex = 0;
      }
      var imgToAdd = document.createElement("img");
      var container = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      
      imgToAdd.setAttribute("src", arrayImgs[imgIndex]);
      imgToAdd.classList.add('class-img');

      var x = event.clientX;  
      var y = event.clientY;
    
      //generate a random width form the image
      var rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 33) + 20;
      var imgWidth = ((window.innerWidth / 100) * rndInt);
      
      //parse image width
      imgWidth = Math.floor(imgWidth);

      imgToAdd.setAttribute("width", imgWidth );
      imgToAdd.setAttribute("height", "auto" );
      var imgHeight = imgToAdd.height;
      
      //place the image in the middle of mouse X and Y
      imgToAdd.style.position = "absolute";
      imgToAdd.style.left = (x - (imgWidth / 2))+'px';
      imgToAdd.style.top = (y - (imgWidth / 2))+'px';
      
      container.appendChild(imgToAdd);
      imgIndex = imgIndex + 1;
  });
 });
});
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.class-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: bounce 1s;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s;
  -moz-animation: bounce 1s;
}
```

```html
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
<div id="myCanvas" class="container">CLICK ME</div>
```

It is not clear from the code in the question whether the link is placed in the body of the document or in its head. It probably ought to be placed in the head before any of your own styling so you can if required overwrite the linked css's styling.

The second problem, working out the img's height, will need you to load the img (could be in the same place as now but with `opacity: 0`), and then look at its height and then reposition it and set `opacity: 1` and set the animation.